# bash script for attaching file with mutt

Tags: bash, mutt

i have a bash script with the below contents

```
 #!/bin/bash
  mv  /test.txt/ /test/date "+%d-%m-%y"`.txt
```

Need to attach this file using mutt and send an email.
Kindly help

Comment: The bash script contains an unbalanced backquote, so it will never run. It contains other __very__ strange things (such as referencing a _directory_ named `test.txt` directly under the filesystem root, and a `date` executable under `/test/` instead of under `/bin/`...) The best way to attach a script to an email is to pack it into a `.zip` or `.tar.gz` archive and attach it using the desired program. Or do you need a _command line_ command to send an email with an attached file?

Comment: Are you looking for `mv test.txt test"$(date '+%d-%m-%y')".txt`?

Comment: hi sorry for the backqoute. what i am looking for is to send an email with attached file.

Comment: Just use the magic words `man mutt`.

Answer (score 0):

`-a` to attach a file

```
mutt -s "mail subject" example@address.com < /path/to/message/body.txt -a /path/to/text.txt
```